# Using Depth First Search to traverse a Matrix to find out Percolation

Tags: java, recursion, matrix, depth-first-search

I'm trying to write a boolean method that will return if a matrix is "full" or not

(A full site is an open site that can be connected to an open site in the top row via a chain of neighboring (left, right, up, down) open sites.)

for the grid, true = open site

I'm still learning recursion and I read somewhere that DFS is used to solve mazes so I'm trying that route...

Right now I just added a same size matrix to track if that spot has been visited or not. I'm trying to just figure out a way. Given an initial spot, to see if I can traverse to the top row using recursion..

I know this is wrong, someone's help can guide me. I have stuck right now and I'm kinda frustrated. This is what i got so far

```
private boolean [][] grid;
private boolean [][] visited;
private int size;

public boolean isFull(int i, int j)
{
    int row = i-1;
    int col = j-1;


    //base cases        
    if(row < 0 || row > size || col < 0 || col > size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of Bounds Exception");
    }

    if(row == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if(visited[row][col]) {
        return false;
    }

    visited[row][col] = true;

    //top
    isFull(row, col-1);
    //bot
    isFull(row, col+1);
    //left
    isFull(row-1, col);
    //right
    isFull(row+1, col);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to throw an exception for the first base case, simply return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this [website](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/24percolation/) that uses java and a recursive method to check if a grid percolates. There is another way to check by using the "Union Find" algorithm:

```
/*
    To start and for convenience, set each elements's
    id to its own index value
*/

//number of elements to test
int n; 

int[] treeSize = new int[n];
int[] id = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    id[i] = i;
    treeSize[i] = 1;
}

void makeUnion(int p, int q){
    /*
       Connect smaller tree to the bigger one by
       making root of the smaller tree the child of
       the root of the bigger tree.
    */
    int pRoot = getRoot(p);
    int qRoot = getRoot(q);

    treeSize[pRoot] < treeSize[qRoot] ?
      id[pRoot] = qRoot, treeSize[qRoot] += treeSize[pRoot] :
      id[qRoot] = pRoot, treeSize[pRoot] += treeSize[qRoot] ;
}

bool connected(int p, int q){
  return getRoot(p) == getRoot(q);
 }

int getRoot(int i){
   /*
     Transverse through parent
     pointers in the tree
     until root is reached
   */
   while(i != id[i]){         //check if root
      id[i] = id[ id[i] ];  //flatten tree a bit(path compression by 1/2) points to grand-parent now
      i = id[i];                          //move up one level
   }
   return i;
}
```

You iterate through the entire grid and use `makeUnion` to connect two spots if they are open and adjacent and use `connected` to check if bottom and top are connected.